# Query String and Custom Controls in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, file-upload

I am working on a website which allows users to upload videos to my site.
I want to display the uploaded videos dynamically i.e. the videos should be visible whenever an user uploads a video.
To do this I have a custom control video player built. It works fine if I provide the "mp4url" directly.
However, if I pass the mp4url using querystring, it is not working.

I have a submit page which allows users to upload videos using a fileupload control, and these are uploaded to "Uploads" folder

```
 //Move through the "Uploads" folder and display the thumbnails of the videos after file has been uploaded
    private void LoadThumbnails()
    {
        foreach (string strfile in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads")))
        {
            ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(strfile);
            imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/Uploads/" + fi.Name;
            imageButton.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
            imageButton.Style.Add("padding", "5px");
            imageButton.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
            imageButton.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imageButton_Click);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);
        }
    }

    //Redirect to the "Videos" page using Querystring
    protected void imageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Videos.aspx?VideoURL=" + ((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl);
    }
```

There is a page called "Videos" which has a video player, it receives "Mp4Url" using the querystring

```
 <cc1:VideoPlayer ID="VideoPlayer1" runat="server" Mp4Url='<%# Request.QueryString["VideoURL"]%>'  Width="400" Height="300" />
```

This is not working, any idea of what changes will rectify this issue?(Issue is the video player is not playing the video)

P.S.

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        VideoPlayer1.Mp4Url = Request.QueryString["VideoURL"];
      }
```

Even the above code in the code behind file for the Videos page is not working.

If i use

```
<cc1:VideoPlayer ID="VideoPlayer1" runat="server" Mp4Url="Uploads/movie.mp4"  Width="400" Height="300" />
```

it's working fine. However, that requires manual allocation of the mp4url.

Comment: When you inspect the querystring in the debugger, what does it show?

Comment: Well, nothing much. All I see is a black screen of the video player

Comment: I mean, set a break point on `VideoPlayer1.Mp4Url = Request.QueryString["VideoURL"];` and inspect the QueryString - what does it show?

Comment: In the call stack, I'm seeing this line " MyWebsite.dll!MyWebsite.Videos.Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 20 
"

Comment: ? I said inspect the `QueryString`.. hover over the object whilst paused in the debugger, it will show the value for it

Comment: The Mp4Url is null in this->VideoPlayer1

Comment: @DGibbs When I removed the code behind file and added  `Mp4Url = '<%= Request.QueryString["VideoURL"] %>' ` in the source of videos.aspx I'm getting this value for Mp4Url after inspecting "<%= Request.QueryString[\"VideoURL\"] %>"

Comment: Okay, I learnt that the ~/ is not always useful :) 
The reason this was not working was

    `imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/Uploads/" + fi.Name;`
I removed the ~/ from the above line and it started to work like a charm :) Thank you for your response @DGibbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I learnt that the ~/ is not always useful :) 
The reason this was not working was

```
imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/Uploads/" + fi.Name;
```

I removed the ~/ from the above line and it started to work like a charm :)